# How do I create a Physx heightfield from a model triangle mesh?

Tags: mesh, physx

My question is clear: I have a mesh defined by its vertices, index... I want to transform it to a heightfield, if someone can provide some example or link to, I will really appreciate.
Thank you very much

Comment: Have you considered rendering your mesh with a shader that colours it in a gradient based on its height?

Comment: @DMGregory then they would somehow extract the colour data from the GPU and build their heightfield grid?